# Bootstrap export shows option to CSV ONLY

Tags: bootstrap-4, bootstrap-table

I have been googling around and checking the docs to see if it is possible to set the bootstrap table export extension to only show **CSV** or specific options. At the moment

```
data-show-export="true"
```

it is showing everything. Has seen here 
[Codepen example](https://codepen.io/jahid-webdev/pen/ObegKN)
Is it possible to set specifics export type(s)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `exportTypes: ['csv']` to `bootstrapTable` options.

you can add more options to this array `['csv', 'excel']` etc...

i have edited your codepen example: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/zmGWLq

More detailes here:

https://bootstrap-table.com/docs/extensions/export/